# Convert string object to active record class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So I am interested if there is a way to convert string to active record class.

**Example:** I have a `User` class which has inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base`.
Is there any way I can convert string `"User"` to `User` class so I can use `ActiveRecord` methods such as `find`, `where`, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`String#constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) returns the value for the constant with the string's name. For `"User"` this is your `User` class:

```
"User".constantize
# => User(id: integer, ...)
```

You can assign this to a variable and call ActiveRecord methods:

```
model = "User".constantize
model.all
# => [#<User id:1>, #<User id:2>, ...]
```

Comment: To be strict, it returns any object bound to given constant name, not only module/class.

Answer (score 3):

You just write in you code

```
str="User"
 class_name=str.constantize
```

and you will get
 like this format data

```
User(id: integer, login: string, name: string, email: string, user_rank: integer
```

User as class name

**Second Method is**
class_name= Object.const_get(str)

Answer (score 3):

safer way:

```
"string".classify.constantize.find(....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead define a method in your string class

```
     def constantize_with_care(list_of_klasses=[])
        list_of_klasses.each do |klass|
           return self.constantize if self == klass.to_s
          end
        raise "Not allowed to constantize #{self}!"
     end
```

Then use

```
 "user".constantize_with_care([User])
```

and now you can do something like this

```
params[:name].constantize_with_care([User])
```

Without any security concern.